# Using flow to create X new records, based on user input X, of a custom object

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, screen-flow, flow-screen-component

Here's the use case:

User creates a course (custom object) that has X sessions.  The goal is to create a screen flow that is launched from the course and asks the user, how many sessions do you want to create?  It will collect some basic values, then create X records of the session object.

It's a little more complex because ideally what we're doing is creating a record collection variable and X records, then looping through each record and collecting a big more information (start time, end time, etc).

So the question is - can i use a loop to create X records based on user input?  I can't quite see how to accomplish this.

Comment: Add records to a collection at the same time as keeping track of the count of how many you have added; use a decision that either returns to adding records or drops out of this "loop", depending on whether your count has reached "x", and inserts the collected set of records after that.